# writing to a file in nasm using system calls

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

As part of an assignment, I'm supposed to write to a file using system calls. Everything works fine except when I try to open the file in gedit (Linux). It says it can't identify the character encoding. Notepad (on Windows) opens the file just fine.

Why doesn't this work on Linux ?

Here's the code:

```
    section .text

    global _start

        _start:
                    mov EAX, 8
                    mov EBX, filename
                    mov ECX, 0700
                    int 0x80
                    mov EBX, EAX
                    mov EAX, 4
                    mov ECX, text
                    mov EDX, textlen
                    int 0x80
                    mov EAX, 6
                    int 0x80
                    mov eax, 1
                    int 0x80
        
    section .data

        filename db "./output.txt", 0
        text db "hello world", 0
        textlen equ $ - text
```

-- update: adding a linefeed character after the output string fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it, see update in the question.

Comment: Post answers as answers, not edits to the question.  I assume you know that 10 years later, but since someone else was already editing this question, might as well fix that :P

Answer (score 2):

change line 3 to this :
`mov ECX, 0x0700`

Comment: octal 0700 is hex `0x1c`.  Or in NASM syntax, `0q700`.  0x700 is an octal mode of `03400`: setgid and sticky, and read-only for owner.  (The line you're changing is the `mode` arg for `creat(2)`.  Normally you'd want to pass `0q666` to let umask mask it down as appropriate.)