# Why does syscall compile in NASM 32 bit output while popa does not compile in 64 bit?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

The [Intel manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf) says that:

- the `syscall` instruction is invalid for compatibility mode (32-bit)
- `popa` is invalid for 64-bit mode

So is there a reason why NASM:

- gives a compilation error `instruction not supported in 64-bit mode` if I use `popa` with `-f elf64`
- does not give give a compilation error if I use `syscall` with `-f elf32`. If I run the executable I get `Illegal instruction (core dumped)` as expected.

Why treat those two cases differently?

Tested with NASM version 2.10.09 on Ubuntu 14.04 (should be OS agnostic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `syscall` instruction exists (and works) on AMD processors in 32 bit mode too. Historically, Intel used the `sysenter` instruction, but when AMD came up with the 64 bit extension, they used their own `syscall` and so when Intel took over the extensions, they also started supporting `syscall`, but only in 64 bit mode.

Comment: I was too naive to think that Intel and AMD would be compatible :-) Accepting since the AMD manuals say that `popa` is illegal in 64-bit and say nothing about `syscall` being illegal in compat mode.

Comment: I have asked if there is a good way to find out the compatible subset at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29833938/what-is-the-compatible-subset-of-intels-and-amds-x86-64-implementations