# Running Intel assembly programming code on AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1090T Processor

Tags: assembly

I have started learning Assembly and videos are based on Intel architecture and my desktop has a AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1090T Processor. 
I want to practice those codes in the few videos I have seen till date but don't know how to setup some environment for running Intel Assembly on AMD Phenom machine.
Your help is very much appreciated....Thanks....

Comment: It's no different than how to set up one on an Intel x86 processor.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980591/how-can-intel-and-amd-be-different-but-still-compatible.  IDK if I should mark this as a duplicate, since it's sort of the opposite question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Intel and AMD make processors that use the *x86 architecture.* If you write an assembly program for Intel processors, it also runs on AMD processors and vice versa. Just follow the instructions in the video, you won't notice a difference.

Comment: Thanks Ross and FUZxxl....So I can install NASM in a VM running Ubuntu 8.1 and then start working in it on assembly code?....

Comment: @KarthikSridharan You don't even need a VM, you can program on your computer directly. If you run a VM, it doesn't matter at all what the host system's CPU is as the VM abstracts away this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks....I asked this specifically since those videos I'm following are for Linux OS....Happy to hear that I can run in a VM without any problem of AMD and Intel clash....

Comment: @KarthikSridharan: Just keep in mind the x86 instruction set is being extended by almost each generation of x86 processors. So like the new AVX instructions may be not supported by older AMD CPU. But if you are following some ASM tutorial videos, don't worry about this, they will stay around 80386 level (year 1985) most of the time. After learning that you will have no problem to read about the last 30y extensions and decide what you need. Your AMD is much more compatible than that. :)