# What does `amd64` mean in Python .whl files?

Tags: python, x86-64, intel, python-wheel, amd-processor

I'm trying to download some Python `.whl` files, but I'm not sure what version I should be downloading.

I have a windows machine with an Intel chip, but all the versions I see use `amd64`, does that mean the versions are for AMD chips only?

Comment: It's a synonym for x86-64.  [The most correct way to refer to 32-bit and 64-bit versions of programs for x86-related CPUs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53364320) .  See also [What EXACTLY is the difference between intel's and amd's ISA, if any?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38516823).  AMD was first, and some software still uses `amd64` as part of their naming of the ISA.  Other Q&As include [How can Intel and AMD be different but still compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37980591) / [Why do Off-the-shelf applications work on both Intel and AMD processors?](//stackoverflow.com/q/832007)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Basic Takeaway

You can download the `amd64` version of the file.

AMD64 is the standard name given to the 64-bit x86 architecture, which your Intel chip probably uses. You can read more about x86-64 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64).

### Short History

Intel wanted to leave the x86 architecture behind and adopt a new architecture that would not be backwards-compatible with pre-existing 32-bit x86 architectures, and in doing so [cut AMD out](https://www.quora.com/Why-didn-t-Intel-extend-x86-to-64-bit-and-get-Microsoft-onboard-before-AMD-then-lock-AMD-out-with-patents-instead-of-the-dead-end-of-Itanium) of the market. To counter this, AMD redeveloped the x86 architecture and presented it as an evolutionary approach for moving to 64-bit chipsets that supported legacy 32-bit code.

Because of this support, AMD's architecture prevailed and Intel was forced to adopt their design. AMD developed the architecture, which is why Python `.whl` files use `amd64` to represent architectures based on `x86-64`.